# Twig: for each month of the Year

Tags: twig

This is strange. If I use `{{ j }}`, I get all 12 numbers, but adding the Twig date filter just echos out "Jan" twelve times.

How do I echo out all months of the year? Do I have a create an array instead?

```
<select>
{% for j in range(1, 12) %}
    <option>{{ j|date('M') }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: variable `j`)) so nice..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because twig treats j as number of seconds from January 1970 (so it's always January).

From twig documentation:

> The date filter accepts strings (it must be in a format supported by
>   the strtotime function), DateTime instances, or DateInterval
>   instances.

This should work:

```
{% for j in range(1, 12) %}
    <option>{{ date('2012-' ~ j ~ '-01') |date('M') }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution given by Cyprian Throwed me the following error

> The function "date" does not exist

So I changed code to

```
{% for j in 1..12 %}
    <option>{{ j |date('2012-' ~ j ~ '-01') |date('M') }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

and this worked for me.... Thanks Cyprian

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
{% for j in 1..12 %}
    <option>{{ '2012-' ~ j ~ '-01' |date('M') }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

is working fine.

Comment: The string needs to be parenthesized, otherwise this will display `2012-1Jan` through `2012-12Jan` because the filter applies only to `'-01'`, then the result `'Jan'` is appended to `'2012-' ~ j `. So the option's content should be `{{ ('2012-' ~ j ~ '-01') |date('M') }}`.